# wireframe after the on cage

Tags: subdivision-surface, wireframe

after i press *On Cage* button in Subdivision modifier - wireframe is hidden.
Did the developer do it intentionally or is it a technical limitation of the program and display the wireframe in this case will be very difficult?
In the first case - I will request a future option on the right click.
Thank you
[image]

Comment: @Marty Fouts it is a pity that they did not penetrate the question. Wireframe **will hide after** clicking _On cage_  button. Check the [screenshot](https://i2.paste.pics/3f716c936b39ea6ebda04eb15652d7e5.png), please. After ckick the button I steel want to see the wireframe **in edit**, not odject mode. And then steel have a question, which is in the first post.

Comment: Seems to be an issue. You can post it at developer.blender.org, but make it clear. You should explain all steps that you do, to avoid misunderstanding like this. Explain that you have wireframe overlay enabled, optimal display disabled.

Comment: @Crantisz thank you Could you check this reproduce steps in [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d_oE4UWMmofNOhIwLJpYFI57Lsm-Isfr/view?usp=sharing), please. Do you think this issue deserves to be published as a bug report?